# Get ID of total_form_count?

Tags: django, django-forms

When using a formset, you need to add `{{formset.management_form}}` to your form. This renders 3 fields, one of which is `TOTAL_FORM_COUNT`. I want to get the ID of this field so that I can modify its value via JS. How can I do that?

I'm trying stuff like `formset.management_form.TOTAL_FORM_COUNT` and `.fields.TOTAL_FORM_COUNT` to get the field, and then I *think* `auto_id` should hold the attribute I need, but I can't figure out how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to get the value of the total_form_count from the field.

When I needed the same however, I got it from within jQuery:

```
$('id_your-model-name_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val()
```

Since I guess you are going to be replacing the value because you manually add more forms via javascript, you are going to have to select the element, to increment/set it. You might as well get it's defined value there.

Comment: You forgot the `#`. I know how to retrieve the value with jQuery, but I wanted a more generic solution in case the ID changes. i.e., I want to do `$('#{{formset.total_forms.id}}').val()` instead.